# Quantum code for Substitution Box

Tags: qiskit, classical-computing, quantum-advantage, computational-models

How to write quantum code(qiskit) for n-bit Substitution Box with minimum number of gate and qubit.

Comment: Are you specifically talking about the AES $S$-box?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It is for any Substitution box of any size having n bit of input and n bit of output.